# C# re-use LINQ expression for different properties with same type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with several `int` properties:

```
class Foo
{
    string bar {get; set;}
    int a {get; set;}
    int b {get; set;}    
    int c {get; set;}
}
```

I have a LINQ expression I wish to use on a `List<Foo>`. I want to be able to use this expression to filter/select from the list by looking at any of the three properties. For example, if I were filtering by `a`:

```
return listOfFoo.Where(f => f.a >= 0).OrderBy(f => f.a).Take(5).Select(f => f.bar);
```

However, I want to be able to do that with any of `f.a`, `f.b`, or `f.c`. Rather than re-type the LINQ expression 3 times, I'd like to have some method which would take an argument to specify which of a, b, or c I want to filter on, and then return that result.

Is there any way to do this in C#? Nothing immediately comes to mind, but it feels like something that should be possible.

Comment: Is it pure linq, or are you pushing out to something else, e.g. Entity Framework? If it's pure linq, you could solve it with reflection

Comment: @AndrewP I'm not familiar with Entity Framework, so I'm probably not using that. It doesn't even necessarily need to be a LINQ solution, as long as I can achieve the same desired effect.

Comment: Have you checked `Dynamic Linq`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> TakeBarWherePositive(IEnumerable<Foo> sequenceOfFoo, Func<Foo, int> intSelector) {
  return sequenceOfFoo
            .Where(f => intSelector(f) >= 0)
            .OrderBy(intSelector)
            .Take(5)
            .Select(f => f.bar);
}
```

Then you would call as

```
var a = TakeBarWherePositive(listOfFoo, f => f.a);
var b = TakeBarWherePositive(listOfFoo, f => f.b);
```

Comment: Wow! So this works... but I'm not sure I understand 100% how still. Can you explain `Func<Foo, int>` a bit more? I'm familiar with using `Func`, but haven't ever seen passing a class type into it like that. Does that usage of `Func<a, b>` basically translate to "a property with type `b` which is in type `a`"? Is there an MSDN page or something which describes this usage?

Comment: `Func<Foo, int>` means "a function that takes in a value of type `Foo`, and returns a value of type `int`." In the example you gave, both `f => f.a` and `f => f.b` are of type `Func<Foo, int>`. You could also do something more exotic, like `f => f.a + 1000`, or something silly like `f => 1000` -- all of those are valid arguments to `TakeBarWherePositive`.

Comment: @nhinkle That's nothing more than a simple delegate pre-written by Microsoft so you don't need to declare your own every single time you need to pass around some methods.

Comment: Of course, it makes sense now. Thanks @Nick - in hindsight that seems obvious, but it never occurred to me to pass it in that way.